# SLF4J logger not performing {} substitutions

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I am currently using slf4j logger in my class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

And although I use the `{}` substitution in my code as below:

```
logger.info("User {} successfully logged in to the system",u.getEmail());
```

Please check my logback configuration below:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} H:${HOSTNAME} - SC:%X{optionalParam} %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Even though I am using the latest stable version slf4j 1.7.25 the `{}` is still not being substituted correctly.

The following text is the output of logger.info:

> "User {} successfully logged in to the system"

I create the logger using LoggerFactory:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CryptoWorks.class);
```

Comment: What slf4j implementation you have in the classpath at runtime ? And what is being logged?

Comment: How are you creating the logger? And what's the output of `logger.info`?

Comment: Please find the updated edit

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation i got to see that the issue was in the encoder pattern that was being used by logback.

I changed the encoder pattern to:

```
 <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} H:${HOSTNAME} - %msg%n</pattern>
 </encoder>
```

And everything started working accordingly and now the {} substitutions are being successfully performed.